# How to send email through GMail using ICS?

Tags: delphi, gmail, icalendar

How can I send email through gmail smtp account using [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/eng/products/ics.html) component?

Comment: Which part of the task are you having trouble with? Can you send e-mail through other SMTP servers, just not Google's?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the MailSnd demo application in the [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/eng/products/ics.html"ICS") component files.

A complete solution for sending by SMTP is shown.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know with ICS but If you want, you can use [Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php) library for this.

http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/public:howto:smtpsend

Answer (score 0):

Try getting yourself familiar with setting up SMTP mail using Outlook or Thunderbird first and once you are happy with that it should be reasonably straightforward to get  the components to work.  The one problem you may have is that Google requires SSL over SMTP which in my experience can be very difficult to set up using openssl on a windows PC.